# In Android Studio 1.1.0, is there a way to change the color of only those method names defined in the current file/class?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, ide

[image]

I can imagine that this might not (ever) be a feature.

(I wouldn't necessarily want "other" method calls to be blue as shown in the second block; blue is just to emphasize what's different from first block.)

If there's a way to just color methods defined in the current class, please advise.

(I want this because my eyes need all the help they can get.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA as of version 14.1. It can be implemented as a plugin, but I'm not aware of any such plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Just documenting, as I was looking for a way to do this and I have found a way that is satisfactory enough to me.

There's a way, but it's a workaround, it will have side effects.

[image: intellij windows]

How:

- Go to File > Settings > Inspections (Choose the Global Profile if necessary).
- Type in the search: `qualified`.
- Tick the checkbox next to "*Instance method call not qualified with 'this'*".
- Click on Severity > Edit severities, add new entry by clicking the green + button.

  - Name it whatever you want.
  - You **must** put it at the **bottom of the list** using the arrows. If you don't, the F2 key will no longer work as you expect it as it will prioritize errors at the top of the list.
  - Set the Error stripe mark to #FFFFFF, or the same color as the scrollbar.
  - Set it bold if you wish.
  - If you want to set a color, you **must** set a background color to white (or black if you have a black interface). If you don't, the color will appear black in most conditions.
- If you really want to, do the same for "*Unnecessary 'this' qualifier*"; there is an additional checkbox to make it only apply to methods and not fields.

Side effects:

- This enables inspections, which is not desired.
- Pointing the mouse cursor onto the method calls will cause a hover text to appear describing the inspection.
- If your code has no errors, no warnings, and no additional informative inspections, pressing F2 will jump through these calls.