# In IntelliJ IDEA, how can I color method calls acting on the current instance?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I find it useful to have fields colored in different way than local variables so that I find it easier to visually read the code flow.

In the same way, I would like to color method calls acting on the current instance, so that they look different from method calls acting on other instances (regardless of their type). This should affect interface methods, inherited methods, abstract methods...

These methods are most of the time self-documenting code, or duplicated code that was refactored but not deemed worthy enough of having another class handle the common logic. Therefore I find it useful to visually see I'm not leaving the responsibility of this class.

How can I achieve this in IntelliJ Idea?

---

*I am writing this question because I have found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494662/in-android-studio-1-1-0-is-there-a-way-to-change-the-color-of-only-those-method/39624358#39624358) related to Android Studio while looking for an answer to this, but when I tried to google/search the question days later it was absolutely painful as it did not come up anywhere in the search results, I did not remember how I found it in the first place. I'm writing this question in the hopes it will be useful to any future reader having the same question.*

Answer (score 1):

There's a way, but it's a workaround, it will have side effects.

[image: intellij windows]

How:

- Go to File > Settings > Inspections (Choose the Global Profile if necessary).
- Type in the search: `qualified`.
- Tick the checkbox next to "*Instance method call not qualified with 'this'*".
- Click on Severity > Edit severities, add new entry by clicking the green + button.

  - Name it whatever you want.
  - You **must** put it at the **bottom of the list** using the arrows. If you don't, the F2 key will no longer work as you expect it as it will prioritize errors at the top of the list.
  - Set the Error stripe mark to #FFFFFF, or the same color as the scrollbar.
  - Set it bold if you wish.
  - If you want to set a color, you **must** set a background color to white (or black if you have a black interface). If you don't, the color will appear black in most conditions.
- If you really want to, do the same for "*Unnecessary 'this' qualifier*"; there is an additional checkbox to make it only apply to methods and not fields.

Side effects:

- This enables inspections, which is not desired.
- Pointing the mouse cursor onto the method calls will cause a hover text to appear describing the inspection.
- If your code has no errors, no warnings, and no additional informative inspections, pressing F2 will jump through these calls.